# Function/code to get previous quarter start date and end date from current timestamp

Tags: python, timestamp, python-3.6

I am trying to get the start date and end date of the previous quarter from the current timestamp.

ex: today date is 05/17/2020
I need to get the output as below:
output:
start date: 01/01/2020
end date: 31/03/2020

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python get first and last day of current calendar quarter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36793381/python-get-first-and-last-day-of-current-calendar-quarter)

Comment: It's not exact same question but modifying it shouldn't be hard.