# How do I get the correspondent day of the quarter from a date field?

Tags: python, date

I have a dataset where the dates are between `5/1/2016` and `5/21/2016`. I would like to create a new variable `day_quarter` which will be the correspondent day of the quarter.
For example:

The first day in the Q2 is April 1st so, May 15th would be 45/91 for example.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406131/is-there-a-python-function-to-determine-which-quarter-of-the-year-a-date-is-in helps ?

Comment: This has been asked in the comment provided above.

Comment: The code on the link above was not exactly what I was looking for. The solution provided by @Stanley R works great!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
import datetime
def day_in_quarter(date):
    q2 = (datetime.datetime.strptime("4/1/{0:4d}".format(date.year), "%m/%d/%Y")).timetuple().tm_yday
    q3 = (datetime.datetime.strptime("7/1/{0:4d}".format(date.year), "%m/%d/%Y")).timetuple().tm_yday
    q4 = (datetime.datetime.strptime("10/1/{0:4d}".format(date.year), "%m/%d/%Y")).timetuple().tm_yday

    cur_day =  date.timetuple().tm_yday
    if (date.month < 4):
        return cur_day
    elif (date.month < 7):
        return cur_day - q2 + 1    
    elif (date.month < 10):
        return cur_day - q3 + 1  
    else:
        return cur_day - q4 + 1          

print day_in_quarter(datetime.datetime.strptime("5/15/2016", "%m/%d/%Y"))
```