# Convert from year-date to year-quarter in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of dates in the format '2000-01', and I want to convert them to '2000q1' accordingly. My question is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632766/python-pandas-get-fiscal-quarter-from-fiscal-year-and-month-for-uk), but I'm not sure how the frequency function is being used there. I've written this code which works, but it's not robust and certainly not efficient:

```
periods = ['2000-01', '2000-02', '2000-03', '2000-04', '2000-05', '2000-06']
lst = []
for quarter in periods:
    year, month = quarter.split('-')[0], quarter.split('-')[1]
    q1, q2, q3, q4 = ['01', '02', '03'], ['04', '05', '06'], ['07', '08', '09'], ['10', '11', '12']
    if month in q1:
        month = 'q1'
    if month in q2:
        month = 'q2'
    if month in q3:
        month = 'q3'
    if month in q4:
        month = 'q4'
    lst.append(year+month)
```

What's the best way to do this? Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_periods`:

```
periods = ['2000-01', '2000-02', '2000-03', '2000-04', '2000-05', '2000-06']

s = pd.to_datetime(periods, format='%Y-%m').to_period('Q')
```

Output:

```
PeriodIndex(['2000Q1', '2000Q1', '2000Q1', '2000Q2', '2000Q2', '2000Q2'], dtype='period[Q-DEC]', freq='Q-DEC')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`PeriodIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html):

```
per = pd.PeriodIndex(periods, freq='Q')
print (per)
PeriodIndex(['2000Q1', '2000Q1', '2000Q1', '2000Q2', '2000Q2', '2000Q2'],
             dtype='period[Q-DEC]', freq='Q-DEC')
```

And if need lowercase `q` add [`PeriodIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.strftime.html):

```
per = pd.PeriodIndex(periods, freq='Q').strftime('%Yq%q')
print (per)
Index(['2000q1', '2000q1', '2000q1', '2000q2', '2000q2', '2000q2'], dtype='object')
```