# Sleek way to calculate quarter in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Is there a sleekest way to calculate the quarter for today's date? I know there are bunch of solutions over here but I am looking for something slick which doesn't need any other library that datetime.

I am currently calculating week by using the following code which gives me output for week: 2017-26

```
import datetime as DT

varWeek = (str(DT.date.today().isocalendar()[0]) + "-" + 
           str(DT.date.today().isocalendar()[1]))
```

I need a quarter for today's date in the following format.

'2017-Q2'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Python function to determine which quarter of the year a date is in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406131/is-there-a-python-function-to-determine-which-quarter-of-the-year-a-date-is-in)

Answer (score 4):

```
def quarter(date):
    return '{}-Q{}'.format(date.year, (date.month - 1) // 3 + 1)
```

or

```
def quarter(date):
    a, b = divmod(date.month, 3)
    return '{}-Q{}'.format(date.year, a + bool(b))
```

Test it:

```
>>> quarter(datetime.date.today())
'2017-Q2'
```

Comment: A sleek way indeed!