# How to split a date column into day/month/year columns using python

Tags: python, csv, datetime, text

I have a csv file with just one column 'date' formatted as integer:

| date |
| --- |
| 20181231 |
| 20190107 |
| 20210329 |
| ... |

The solution would be to split the integer into different columns to represent day, month, year and quarter, like:

| date | day | month | year | quarter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20181231 | 31 | 12 | 2018 | 4 |
| 20190107 | 07 | 01 | 2019 | 1 |
| 20210329 | 29 | 03 | 2021 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I would appreciate every kind of solution but I should resolve it using a python program **without** using pandas library.

So I write something like this:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('date.csv', 'r'))
writer = csv.writer(open('datesplit.csv', 'w'))

for line in reader: 
    year = line[0][:3]
    month = line[0][4:5]
    day = line[0][6:]

    writer.writerow(year)
    writer.writerow(month)
    writer.writerow(day)
```

it is not working a you can imagine,

Thanks for helping

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I see `python` tagged, but no lines of python code; thus, my downvote.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetime:

```
import csv
import datetime

csvreader = csv.reader(open('date.csv', 'r'))
csvwriter = csv.writer(open('datesplit.csv', 'w'))

next(csvreader)
csvwriter.writerow(['date', 'day', 'month', 'year', 'quarter'])

for line in csvreader: 
    mydate = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[0], '%Y%m%d')
    csvwriter.writerow([line, mydate.day, mydate.month, mydate.year, (mydate.month-1)//3 + 1 ])
```

More information about quarter: [Is there a Python function to determine which quarter of the year a date is in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406131/is-there-a-python-function-to-determine-which-quarter-of-the-year-a-date-is-in)

More information about csv in python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html