# Creating a new folder with a new name every 3 months?

Tags: python, directory

Lets say I have a program that will run every 3 months, I want it to create a new folder with the name `2022Quarter1`. Then when I run it again 3 months later, I want it to say `2022Quarter2`, etc. Then when a new year comes in, that new year first quarter will be called `2023Quarter1`, and so on.

I wrote this part of the program, just so I have an idea of what I want my end goal to be:

```
import os

for i in range(4):
    i+=1
    num=i
    
try:
    os.makedirs(f'C:/users/desktop/quarters/{yearNum}Quarter{num}')
except FileExistsError:
    # directory already exists
    pass
```

Comment: Using Python's `datetime` you could get the current year and quarter. Also, see this question: [Is there a Python function to determine which quarter of the year a date is in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406131/is-there-a-python-function-to-determine-which-quarter-of-the-year-a-date-is-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around this by using Python's [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module:

- Current date: `current_date = datetime.datetime.today()`
- Current year: `current_year = current_date.year`
- [Current quarter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406131/is-there-a-python-function-to-determine-which-quarter-of-the-year-a-date-is-in): `current_quarter = 1 + (current_date.month - 1) // 3`