# How to find Quarter Aging in Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python

Using date, I have already created Quarter column in pandas dataframe

df['Quarter'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).quarter

Now, i am looking for Quarter aging as a calculated column like below

df['Quarter Aging'] =  ????

so that I can compare current quarter and Last quarter sales differences dynamically when years are passing in the sales reporting.
Expected output is
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT4h7.png)

For example, If my Current Quarter is 2022-Q4, then my Quarter aging is 0
Likewise,

2022-Q4 = 0

2022-Q3 = -1

2022-Q2 = -2

2022-Q1 = -3

2021-Q4 = -4

2021-Q3 = -5

2021-Q2 = -6

2021-Q1 = -7

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

2018-Q1 = -19

[Click here to see expected column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i51tg.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Essentially you are asking how to get time difference in quarters. Perhaps answers to this question could help https://stackoverflow.com/q/1406131/1328439. Can you use Pandas?

Comment: Yes, i am using pandas. And the link you shared is not helping me to calculate quarter aging,

I already calculated Quarter by using date column, Now I am finding out a way to calculate Quarter aging or Quarter relative number

Comment: So that I can always use Quarter aging = 0 & -1 for my Current quarter and previous quarter calculations dynamically irrespective of Years passing in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function with `df.apply` method like this.

```
df["quarter_aging"] = df["quarter"].apply(q_age)


def q_age(quarter):
    q = quarter.split("-")
    year = int(q[0])
    quarter = int(q[1][1])
    quarter_aging = ((year - 2022) * 4 ) + (quarter - 4)
    return(quarter_aging)
```

Comment: Yes, Its working and giving me the expected column values. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Rashmi, How can we make that number "4" dynamic, I am asking this because now we jumped into 2023 and this code is not working. 

now If my Current Quarter is 2023-Q1, then my Quarter aging is 0 Likewise,

2023-Q1 = 0, 

2022-Q4 = -1, 

2022-Q3 = -2, 

2022-Q2 = -3, 

2022-Q1 = -4,

Comment: Hi Yash, Do you want to make the quarter dynamic or the 2022 year dynamic here? I have added 4 here because there are 4 quarters in any year.

Comment: If you want to get the current year here, first import date module like this on the top. -->
from datetime import date
  
and instead of 2022 add this --> int(date.today().year)

Comment: As per your formula, I am getting Quarter aging = "-3" for the 2023-Q1. But it supposes to be quarter aging = "0"

Comment: Now, the expected output should be like this

Quarter aging for 2023-Q1 ----> 0 ,,,,,
 

Quarter aging for 2022-Q4 ----> -1 ,,,,,,




Quarter aging for 2022-Q3----> -2,,,,,,,





Quarter aging for 2022-Q2----> -3,,,,,,,





Quarter aging for 2022-Q1----> -4 ,,,,,,,

Comment: To get the output you have posted, you can use this.--> quarter_aging = ((year - 2023) * 4 ) + (quarter - 1)

Comment: Hi, This works. Thank you Rashmi.
And i have made it dynamic now.

-----------------------


my_date =  dt.date.today()    
year, week_num, day_of_week = my_date.isocalendar()  
CY = year

and 

CQ = df['Quarter'].max()

Then,

 quarter_aging = ((year - CY) * 4 ) + (quarter - CQ)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider to separate year and the quarter into different column. For example 2022Q4 became `year = 2022` and `quarter = 4`. That way you could simply get quarter aging by using the following function:

```
def compute_quarter_aging(year, quarter, current_year, current_quarter):
    return 4 * (year - current_year) - (current_quarter - quarter)
```

In your case `current_year` is 2022 and `current_quarter` is 4.

In case your data has already been that way you could use python slice to get quarter from string year and quarter. But from your question, I see that you clearly get year and quarter from date. You should just directly separate them to different column instead of placing them on the same column.

Comment: This works and but it's not dynamic. It should run when the year gets changed in the future. Thanks,

Comment: Now the year gets changed, Can you please assist here to make it dynamic

Comment: Now, the expected output should be like this Quarter aging for 2023-Q1 ----> 0 ,,,,, Quarter aging for 2022-Q4 ----> -1 ,,,,,, Quarter aging for 2022-Q3----> -2,,,,,,, Quarter aging for 2022-Q2----> -3,,,,,,, Quarter aging for 2022-Q1----> -4